# Datastax driver examples

Tags: maven, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am a newbie to dependency Management tool like Maven. I am trying to execute the examples on https://github.com/datastax/java-driver. But, I have build errors. For example project, `<parent>` tag in `pom.xml` has following error: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:clirr-maven-plugin:2.7:check (execution: default, phase: compile)`.

I was able to download the binary tarball with jars, and execute the example code. But, not sure how to remove that error and build with maven.  Is there anything that I have to include in the parent pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what could be going on here, but is it possible you are running with an older version of Maven?  DataStax java-driver requires Maven 3.2.x+ to build if I recall correctly.